# Wordpress prepare fails...?

Tags: wordpress

Ok... I got another WP problem now.

For my WP theme, i have some special things. For example, i have a table containing some stuff.

when i insert (in this case update) to this table i use $wpdb, like the code below:

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $table_name SET
    `title` = '$title',
    `text` = '$text',
    `image` = '$image',
    `thumbnail` = '$thumb',
    `show` = $sql_show,
    `order` = $order,
    `language` = '$language',
    `type` = '$type'

    WHERE `id` = $id 
;");
$wpdb->query($sql);
```

I have also tried this:

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $table_name SET
    `title` = %s,
    `text` = %s',
    `image` = %s,
    `thumbnail` = %s,
    `show` = %d,
    `order` = %d,
    `language` = %s,
    `type` = %s                
    WHERE `id` = $id 
;", $title, $text, $image, $thumb, $show, $order, $language, $type);
```

Both of them works, EXCEPT when the $text contains a "%". If it contains this, the $sql is blank. Of coure i could change all the "%" to "percent", but that resolution is not acceptable! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%` has to be escaped with a percent, so replace a single percent with a double percent in `$text`: `$text = str_replace('%', '%%', $text)`

Comment: Yea, that did dit the trick, but i thought thar prepare() would do all the escapes for me?

Comment: I think that it doesn't do this, because you can use the `%` to mask search queries. So if you use `$wpdb->prepare()` on a custom search query containing the wildcard `%` signs, your query won't work if those are escaped.

Comment: @gubbfett Yea, I would have thought the same thing for your second case. My solution came from [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks), which makes sense for your first case, since the values become part of the query string.